# Can someone explain me the reason for loading these -> display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;

Tags: css, browser, display

is there a reason why this get loaded?

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Thanks for any answers!

Best,
One

Comment: Could you elaborate on "get loaded"? It's difficult to understand your question. If you're wondering why there are different names for the same property, it's simply because some browsers support some values while others support others.

Comment: I am customizing my wp bootstrap starter theme and I just found these -webkit-box etc. for several css. I understand that are prefixes for different browsers but my major question is if there is an order I have put them in the css because as I understand the css get processed line by line.

Especially for the display property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are CSS Vendors or browser prefixes. Some CSS properties are not fully supported in all browsers, and even when the property is supported - it sometimes must be referenced with an alternate name.

- `-webkit-` is for webkit browsers - these include Chrome and Safari, some version of Opera.
- `-ms-` is for Internet Explorer.
- un-prefixed value is for browsers that don't need a special name prefix.

If you still need additional help understanding what CSS properties need these prefixes, you should check this reference:

https://caniuse.com/